# Django - Reverse for view function not found

Tags: python, django-1.11

I am using Django 1.11.21 and I am trying to load my application in a Django project. I keep getting this error:

```
Reverse for 'wfpdocs_browse' not found. 'wfpdocs_browse' is not a valid view function or pattern name.
```

This is how my template looks like:

```
<li id="nav_staticmaps"><a href="{% url "wfpdocs_browse" %}">{% trans "Static Maps" %}</a></li>
```

In my urls.py file I have:

```
url(r'^$', TemplateView.as_view(template_name='wfpdocs/document_list.html'), name='wfpdocs_browse'),
```

This application used to work but after an update it stopped.

My urls.py file looks like this:

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', TemplateView.as_view(template_name='wfpdocs/document_list.html'), name='wfpdocs_browse'),
    url(r'^rss/$', WFPDocumentsFeed(), name='wfpdocs_rss'),
    url(r'^api/', include(api.urls)),
    url(r'^upload/$', login_required(DocumentUploadView.as_view()), name='wfpdocs_upload'),
    url(r'^(?P<slug>[\w-]+)/$', wfpdocs.document_detail, name='wfpdocs_detail'),
    url(r'^(?P<slug>[\w-]+)/update$', login_required(DocumentUpdateView.as_view()),
        name="wfpdocs_update"),
    url(r'^(?P<slug>[\w-]+)/remove$', wfpdocs.document_remove, name='wfpdocs_remove'),
    url(r'^(?P<slug>[\w-]+)/download/?$', wfpdocs.document_download, name='wfpdocs_download'),
]
```

Comment: try using {% url 'wfpdocs_browse' %}  {% url 'wfpdocs_browse' %} in your urls.py file 
Just by replacing " with '

Comment: @FarhanAnsari In my urls.py file?

Comment: Yes in your urls.py file

Comment: Sorry it's not clear how I am supposed to edit my url file. See edited question.

Comment: What if you replace your double quotes by simple ones here: `<a href="{% url 'wfpdocs_browse' %}">`?

Comment: @olinox14I tried that as well. I get the same error.